# Watchman Error with ember-cli

Tags: facebook, ember.js, ember-cli, watchman

I am trying to follow the examples in Ember 101. I have worked through this code once before without any issue. After reinstalling my ubuntu 14.04 for unrelated reasons I am getting an error [see bellow] when I run ember serve in my console.

I tried the solution to this problem at: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch. I also added "node_modules" and "bower_components" to the .watchmanconfig ignore_dirs per: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4101 without effect.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong/have installed incorrectly?

Error: A non-recoverable condition has triggered.  Watchman needs your help!
The triggering condition was at timestamp=1449200416: inotify-add-watch(/home/john/Practice/borrowers/tests/unit/models) -> The user limit on the total number of inotify watches was reached; increase the fs.inotify.max_user_watches sysctl
All requests will continue to fail with this message until you resolve
the underlying problem.  You will find more information on fixing this at
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch

```
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/john/Practice/borrowers/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/sane/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:202:17)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

Answer (score 15):

I realize this is an old thread, but in case somebody else stumbles here I was able to solve this on my machine by executing the following commands...

```
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
$ watchman shutdown-server
```

The next time I ran `ember build --watch`, everything worked.

For a much better explanation, see...

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13751/kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached
- https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#system-specific-preparation

Comment: This helped me with my React-native app!

Comment: This helped me on Ubuntu 17.04. Cheers

Answer (score 9):

If you want to permanently modify your system you can put this commands:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
watchman shutdown-server
```

It has happened to me after upgrading ember to 2.5.0 on my Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: this permanent fix was much better for me as it takes into account rebooting of the server.